# Text is not centering using flexbox

Tags: css, center, flexbox

Goal: to center text which is contained in a `div` and is a sibling of a `div` that contains the `video` element.

the problem: I'm using flexbox to see if I can justify the div's content center and align its items center along the vertical axis. It centers along the x-axis nicely, but doesn't center along the y-axis.

Any suggestions?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
}
.text {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video poster="http://www.thecanyon.com/assets/css/images/grandcanyon1.jpg" muted="true" autoplay="true">
    <source src="assets/Homepagevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>This is a cool video landing page</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post JSFiddle or a Code Snippet!

Comment: @Druzion - you're free to edit the question and do the same

Comment: @j08691 I was, but you got there first! Also, I was informing user388... that he should do that from now on.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is...the text IS centered. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MKyGQN

Answer (score 5):

Add width and height 100% to .text then add `text-align:center`

[Codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adNGEd/)

Answer (score 0):

1 way for achieving this i.e. centering the text vertically is that by specifying the height of the flex container and setting the "margin" property of your text to "auto" and if you want the text to center along the entire page set the height this way:

```
.text {
height: 100%;
}
```

Add the above to the existing styles for the flex container, and add this too:

```
.text p {
margin: auto;
}
```

The above can be used to center the text inside the flex container, no matter how high the flex container is in height. This will work with any value for the "flex-direction" property of the flex container.

Answer (score -1):

This is the way you should implement it:

```
.text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox is overkill for your needs, try using position: absolute since you got elements already out of the flow.

Relevant CSS

```
.text {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 4em;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2em);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.text {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 4em;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2em);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video poster="http://www.thecanyon.com/assets/css/images/grandcanyon1.jpg" muted="true" autoplay="true">
    <source src="assets/Homepagevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>This is a cool video landing page</p>
</div>
```